# How to split one column of data into two?

Tags: r, stringr

I have looked through similar examples but struggling to get this to work with my data. I want to split one column of data into two, Ortho Group and Score.

[image]

Comment: use `separate` from `tidyverse` read [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.3/topics/separate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `separate` from the `tidyr` package and assuming your data is called `df`:

```
separate(df, col = Orthogroup.Mean_Identity, sep = ",", into = c("Orthogroup", "Mean_Identity"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `df` is the name of your data frame, you can try `tstrsplit` from `data.table`, e.g.,

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,tstrsplit(Orthogroup.Mean_Identity,",")]
```